# How I can remove only data from elastic search index not the complete index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

I have one ELK index available using that I am showing visual dashboard.

My requirement is that I need to empty or remove the data only , not the index it self. How i can achieve this. I googled a  lot . I am getting solution to remove the index, but i need only to remove the data so index will remain there.
I want to achieve this dynamically using command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete all the data in the index if there's not too much of it:

```
POST my-index/_delete_by_query?q=*&wait_for_completion=false
```

Comment: please note though that this is a very inefficient way of removing data from Elasticsearch

Comment: @warkolm Yes, it is very inefficient indeed, but that's the only way to do it without removing the index and with what ES has to offer. That's why I added "if there's not too much data"